# html meta tags for mobile devices

Tags: html, mobile, meta-tags

I have a block of html code, which is mainly meta tags.  I'm trying to re-design my layout for mobile devices, so I want to know if the meta tags that I'm using are necessary for a mobile layout.  The block of code is provided below:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge,chrome=1">
<title>ConquestRealms - Home</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on">
```

Comment: Side note: is this for a website or an app? Because I **hate** it when websites use `user-scalable=no`.

Answer (score 19):

whether or not they are necessary depends on what "mobile" device you are trying to target.

I've used as little as:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

and achieved decent results across a number of mobile devices using just Respond.js and @media queries.

may be helpful:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design

http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices

https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

Comment: I'm trying to target as many mobile devices as I can.  If you've gotten decent results from just the viewport meta tag, then is it fair to say that I'll get even better results for mobile devices by using handheldfriendly, mobileoptimized, and cleartype meta tags?

Comment: Any way you could explain what the tags mean in this answer? Specifically the MobileOptimized tag, which lead me here in a search.

Comment: @MikeLyons: The MobileOptimized tag can be used to _force_ mobile layout on IE Mobile (most common use I would say): "Setting the MOBILEOPTIMIZED meta tag is equivalent to the Layout menu Desktop selection. When the MOBILEOPTIMIZED meta tag is set Internet Explorer Mobile does not modify the layout at all for the page containing the meta tag." (read more: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb431690.aspx).

Comment: Some links are off now (2020)

Answer (score 3):

What you have is already pretty good, but do not forget to add `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of your html file. I found that there have been cases where this has significantly effected the look on a mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

I like to include design meta-tags also. Not mentioned in previous responses. They allow full screen display and change the color of the browser bar. Nice!

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ff0000" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="application-name" content="My Web App">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Mobile rules">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="red">
```